Tracing software framework to support blind people, and, development of blind tracing apps (on Android)
Some apps such as Write It! Japanese  by Jernung on the Google Play store allow you to trace, and, learn. I was wondering what can be done to exploit the idea of tracing to support blind people, (and, of course, make them enjoy their interactions with the smartphone!).
Hello, I am trying to find or develop a framework and related apps that used it that enabled blind people to interact with traces on screen via specific software.
The software would use sound feedback to support the traces. In some cases, the app may also produce a vibration (at the expensive extent of battery power drain and discomfort, thus such a vibration feature would have to be used sparingly by software developers).
With TalkBack, we have braille input, but what if we also had widgets that catered for entering a specific "trace mode" for entering text, and, do stuff with tracing or that required a trace (such, as: e.g., tracing, text
In this mode, in one configuration, sounds were made to guide direction, and (virtual pen lifting or placing, if this was not done automatically in a way that depended on pen position. In the latter case, sounds could be made for trace entering and exiting (at those times where the finger touched those positions).
One application would teach a blind person to trace letters, presented one at a time on screen, and then, once practiced and learned, the blind person could even perhaps use the information to trace the character on some off screen medium, to make an action of appreciation or binding interaction with another person, (which, perhaps could see, or it could be just something on sand with a stick, which could be felt).
In another application different traces would be learned, and then swiped on screen to make different sound effects. The swipe sound, besides confirming to the swipe path traced, could also depend on the on screen position. You could use a second finger (or tap in the case of one fingered individuals), to enable/disable (or toggle), on screen tracing.
The trace software could make two different sounds (perhaps, using two different insurgents producing different sound timbre), one specifying the direction of movement of the finger, the other specifying the direction of the invitation of movement (the direction, and, perhaps, also the speed, in which the finger moves, which change continuously, and, so does the sound).
The sound could be emitted according to a different sound per compass direction, so as to make them different. The blind user would know these, and a third sounds set would be used to correct finger misguided corrections/aka wrong movements.
